Is this layout possible with SwiftUI?
I have been trying to build the following layout with SwiftUI.

Initially I built most of it with a Grid, embedded in a ScrollView. Then I thought I could add the list part at the bottom, but Lists can't be embedded in ScrollViews with SwiftUI, unlike in UIKit where you can embed a UITableView in a UIScrollView if you want.
Then I tried removing the ScrollView, and using a List with multiple sections, with the Grid in the first section, but that didn't work either.
Do I basically have to build a custom list using LazyVStack?
I don't need any of List's built in functionality like selection or row actions.
Thank you for taking the time to read my post.

Why are you trying to embed a List inside of a ScrollView? Lists are scrollable, so you just need the list itself. I'm confused on how a vanilla List won't work on the bottom

Do you want the last section (the one with "Title" and "Detail") to be scrollable independently from the other sections? You seem to be against the idea of building a custom list using LazyVStack. Why? "I don't need any of List's built in functionality like selection or row actions." That's an argument for building your own list, not against. For such specific requirements, building your own list is definitely the way to go. The appearance of the built in List could very well change in future iOS versions.

If you are willing to use some underscore-prefixed APIs, you can make your own List in a very reusable way.

I have implemented your above requirements with LazyVStack. You may check my below code and change it accordingly. also you may add buttons or actions on them.
import SwiftUI


var screenWidth: Double {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
}

var screenHeight: Double {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
}

struct NoSeparatorListV<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    self.content()
                }
            }
        } else {
            List {
                self.content()
            }
            .onAppear {
                UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
            }.onDisappear {
                UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine
            }
        }
    }
}

class LabelInfo {
    var labelName: String
    var labelValue: String
    var labelID: String
    init(labelName: String, labelValue: String, labelID: String) {
        self.labelName = labelName
        self.labelValue = labelValue
        self.labelID = labelID
    }
}
var label1 = LabelInfo(labelName: "Label1", labelValue: "Value1", labelID: "1")
var label2 = LabelInfo(labelName: "Label2", labelValue: "Value2", labelID: "2")
var label3 = LabelInfo(labelName: "Label3", labelValue: "Value3", labelID: "3")
var labelInfoV: [LabelInfo] = [label1, label2, label3]
var labelInfoH1: [LabelInfo] = [label1, label2]
var labelInfoH2: [LabelInfo] = [label1, label2, label3]
struct StackOverFlow: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
            NoSeparatorListV {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .resizable()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .frame(height: screenHeight * 0.30) // assuming height of image is 40% of any scree size
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding([.trailing,.leading,.top], 12)
                ForEach(labelInfoV, id: \.labelID) { label in
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                            Text(label.labelName)
                            Text(label.labelValue)
                        })
                        .padding([.leading,.trailing], 8)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding([.trailing,.leading,.top], 12)
                }
                HStack {
                    // width of them should equal to (screenWidth - (trailing + leading + allOtherGapsPaddingValues))
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                        Text("Label4")
                        Text("Value4")
                    })
                    .frame(width: (screenWidth - 32)/2)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding([.leading], 8)

                    VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                        Text("Label4")
                        Text("Value4")
                    })
                    .frame(width: (screenWidth - 32)/2)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding([.trailing], 8)
                }
                .padding([.trailing,.leading,.top], 12)

                HStack {
                    // width of them should equal to (screenWidth - (trailing + leading + allOtherGapsPaddingValues))
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                        Text("Label5")
                        Text("Value5")
                    })
                    .frame(width: (screenWidth - 48)/3)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding([.leading], 8)

                    VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                        Text("Label6")
                        Text("Value6")
                    })
                    .frame(width: (screenWidth - 48)/3)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding([.trailing], 8)

                    VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                        Text("Label7")
                        Text("Value7")
                    })
                    .frame(width: (screenWidth - 48)/3)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding([.trailing], 8)
                }
                .padding([.trailing,.leading,.top], 12)

                NoSeparatorListV {
                    ForEach(1..<10) { i in
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Title: \(i)")
                                    .background(Color.red)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Details")
                            }
                            .padding([.top], 4)
                            .padding([.trailing], 8)
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(height: 0.5)
                                .background(Color.green)
                                .opacity(i%2 == 1 ? 0.3 : 0.7)
                        }
                        .padding([.leading], 8)
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding([.trailing,.leading,.top], 12)
            }
        }
        .padding([.bottom,.top],12)
    }
}


#Preview {
    StackOverFlow()
}

NB: You may use forEach loops for those Horizontal Labels using LazyHStack.
